# How to read Microsoft Visio file contents using java?

Tags: java, apache, visio

I created entity relationship diagram in Microsoft Visio. Now I want to read the `.vsd` file contents in Java class.

Is there any Java utility available which can help in reading `.vsd` file ER diagrams?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for that

Comment: Do you have any sample code for this, as I tried but not able to find some helping code.